# Automatic generated json file with php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get a playlist json file generator to work for a little picture slideshow project on my Raspberry Pi.

How do I create a json file with php in this format?

This is my PHP code:

```
function json_read() {
  $link = connect();

  $i = 0;

  $string = "SELECT * FROM Playlist, Bild WHERE Playlist.Bild_idBild = Bild.idBild";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $string);   

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $i[] = array(
                 'file' => $row['Bild.dateiname'],
                 'duration' => $row['Playlist.zeit'],
                 );

    $i++;
  }

  $data = array(
                'playlist' => $i
                );

  echo json_encode($data);

  disconnect();
}
```

How it should look like:

```
{
"playlist": [
    {
        "file": "001.jpg",
        "duration": 5
    },
    {
        "file": "002.jpg",
        "duration": 5
    },
    {
        "file": "003.jpg",
        "duration": 10
    },
    {
        "file": "004.jpg",
        "duration": 5
    },
    {
        "file": "005.jpg",
        "duration": 10
    },
    {
        "file": "006.jpg",
        "duration": 5
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite confusing.

You are incrementing array name.

Rather than this code:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $i[] = array(
            'file' => $row['Bild.dateiname'],
            'duration' => $row['Playlist.zeit'],
        );

        $i++;
    }
```

Use this:

```
 $arr = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $temp['file'] = $row['Bild.dateiname'];
  $temp['duration'] = $row['Playlist.zeit'];
  $arr['playlist'][$i] = $temp;
        $i++;
    }



echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

[while](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.while.php) is not [for](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php) - dont use increment var in this case

need to give the name of the variable semantic:

$i actually $playlist;

```
function json_read() { $link = connect();

    $string = "SELECT * FROM Playlist, Bild WHERE Playlist.Bild_idBild = Bild.idBild";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $string); 

    // create container for playlist elements
    $playlist = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        // add new element onto the end container
        $playlist[] = array(
            'file' => $row['Bild.dateiname'],
            'duration' => $row['Playlist.zeit'],
        );

    }

    $data = array(
        'playlist' => $playlist
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

    disconnect();
}
```